# Google cloud speech to text long audio response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to convert audio to text, but getting result as,

```
LongRunningRecognizeResponse { results: [] }
```

Here is my function,

```
    const audio = {
    uri: `gs://${BUCKET}/${fileName}`,
};

const request = {
    config: {
        encoding: 'LINEAR16',
        sampleRateHertz: 16000,
        languageCode: 'en-US',
    },
    audio: audio,
};

client.longRunningRecognize(request)
    .then(responses => {
        const [operation, initialApiResponse] = responses;

        operation.on('complete', (result, metadata, finalApiResponse) => {
            console.log('complete', result) // LongRunningRecognizeResponse { results: [] }
        });

        operation.on('progress', (metadata, apiResponse) => {
            console.log('progress', apiResponse)
        });

        operation.on('error', err => {
            throw (err);
        });
    })
```

Comment: If this persists and you think this is an issue on Google's side, you can open an [Issue Tracker entry](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and have the engineers take a look at it. You can use this as a [template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187181&template=1161156).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const transcribeLong = async (url, channels) => {
    const nameExtract = url.split('/');
    const fileName = nameExtract[nameExtract.length - 1];
    let localfile;
    try {
        localfile = await download(url);
        fs.writeFileSync(fileName, localfile);
        await storage.bucket(BUCKET).upload(fileName);
        const audio = {
            uri: `gs://${BUCKET}/${fileName}`,
        };
        const request = {
            config: {
                languageCode: `en-US`,
                alternativeLanguageCodes: [`es-MX`, `en-US`],
                encoding: 'LINEAR16',
                sampleRateHertz: 8000,
                audioChannelCount: channels || 2, //changed from 2
                enableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel: true,
            },
            audio,
        };
        const [operation] = await client.longRunningRecognize(request);
        const [response] = await operation.promise();
        return response
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.toString());
    }
};
```

Issues was with wrong channels as argument in request.